# Simple four-function math quiz

Tags: javascript, html5, quiz

I'm working on my first web app and would like some feedback on the code I have completed. I asked for a similar code review a few weeks ago but I have since improved my structure and added some user adjustable settings.

The app is a simple math quiz (addition, subtraction, multiplication, & division questions) where users can adjust several settings based on their needs. I did my best to make it object-oriented and am curious. How could I improve it?

I purchased a few HTML5 books from Amazon and read through them but like most resources (including Mozilla Developer Network) they did a great job of explaining everything but did not really show any examples of how to structure a complete web app with settings, etc.

My approach to structuring was to create a div for each "frame". A "frame" for the title screen, about screen, settings screen, quiz screen, and results screen. Only one "frame" is ever shown at a time and each "frame" has its own code area. Is this a good structure or could it be improved? Could I improve the way I load the current settings and update the settings when they're saved?

The code below includes the complete app structure, an about screen, and a settings screen that can be adjusted and saved by the user (for the session only, adding storage later).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xfyju/2/)

```
<div id="frameHome">
<div align="center">
<p><strong>Math Quiz App</strong></p>
<p><input type="button" id="buttonPlay" value="Play"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="button" id="buttonSettings" value="Settings"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="button" id="buttonAbout" value="About"></p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="frameAbout">
<div align="center">
<p><strong>About</strong></p>
<p>Math Quiz App<br />
Version 1.0</p>
<p><input type="button" id="buttonOK" value="OK"></p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="frameSettings">
<div align="center">
<p><strong>Settings</strong></p>
<p>Operators: 
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxOperators" id="add" /> 
Addition
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxOperators" id="sub" /> 
Subtraction
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxOperators" id="mul" /> 
Multiplication
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxOperators" id="div" /> 
Division
</p>
<p>Number of questions: 
<input type="button" id="buttonQuesMinus" value="&lt;"> <span id="divQues">10</span> <input type="button" id="buttonQuesPlus" value="&gt;">
</p>
<p>Answer style:
<input type="radio" name="radioAnswerStyle" id="fillBlank" />
Fill in the Blank
<input type="radio" name="radioAnswerStyle" id="multipleChoice" /> 
Multiple Choice
</p>
<p>Timer:
<input type="radio" name="radioTimer" id="off" />
Off
<input type="radio" name="radioTimer" id="countdown" /> 
Countdown
<input type="radio" name="radioTimer"  id="elapsed" />
Elapsed
</p>
<p>Time: 
<input type="button" id="buttonTimeMinus" value="&lt;"> <span id="divTime">2:00</span> <input type="button" id="buttonTimePlus" value="&gt;">
</p>
<p>
<input type="button" id="buttonCancel" value="Cancel"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="button" id="buttonSave" value="Save">
</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="frameQuiz">
Quiz
</div>

<div id="frameResults">
Results
</div>

<script>
// Variables
// Settings
var operators = ["add", "sub", "mul", "div"]; // add, sub, mul, AND div
var totalQuestions = 10; // 5 TO 100
var timerStyle = "countdown"; // off OR countdown OR elapsed
var countdownTime = 120; // 30 TO 3600
var answerStyle = "multipleChoice"; // multipleChoice OR fillBlank

// Frames
var frameHome = document.getElementById("frameHome");
var frameAbout = document.getElementById("frameAbout");
var frameSettings = document.getElementById("frameSettings");
var frameQuiz = document.getElementById("frameQuiz");
var frameResults = document.getElementById("frameResults");

var frames = [frameHome, frameAbout, frameSettings, frameQuiz, frameResults];

// Displays frame and hides all other frames
function gotoFrame(frameID) {
    for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
        if (frameID == frames[i].id) {
            // Show frame
            frames[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
            // Hide frame
            frames[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    frameCode(frameID);
}

// Code for each frame, code runs when frame is displayed
function frameCode(frameID) {
    switch (frameID) {


        case "frameHome":
            buttonPlay.onclick = function () { gotoFrame("frameQuiz"); };
            buttonSettings.onclick = function () { gotoFrame("frameSettings"); };
            buttonAbout.onclick = function () { gotoFrame("frameAbout"); };
            break;


        case "frameAbout":
            buttonOK.onclick = function () { gotoFrame("frameHome"); };
            break;


        case "frameSettings":
            // Operators  ----------
                // Get element
                var checkboxOperators = document.getElementsByName("checkboxOperators");

                // Uncheck all
                for (var i = 0; i < checkboxOperators.length; i++) {
                    document.getElementById(checkboxOperators[i].id).checked = false;
                }

                // Check operators based on operators array
                for (var i = 0; i < operators.length; i++) {
                    document.getElementById(operators[i]).checked = true;
                }
            // ------------------------------

            // Number of questions ----------
                var tempTotalQuestions = totalQuestions;

                divQues.innerHTML = tempTotalQuestions;

                // Questions minus
                buttonQuesMinus.onclick = function() { 
                    if (tempTotalQuestions > 5) {
                        tempTotalQuestions -= 5;
                    }

                    divQues.innerHTML = tempTotalQuestions;
                };
                // Questions plus
                buttonQuesPlus.onclick = function() { 
                    if (tempTotalQuestions < 100) {
                        tempTotalQuestions += 5;
                    }

                    divQues.innerHTML = tempTotalQuestions;
                };
            // ------------------------------

            // Answer style ----------
                document.getElementById(answerStyle).checked = true;
            // ------------------------------

            // Timer style ----------
                document.getElementById(timerStyle).checked = true;
            // ------------------------------

            // Countdown time ----------
                var tempCountdownTime = countdownTime;

                divTime.innerHTML = formatTime(tempCountdownTime);

                // Time minus
                buttonTimeMinus.onclick = function() { 
                    if (tempCountdownTime > 30) {
                        tempCountdownTime -= 30;
                    }

                    divTime.innerHTML = formatTime(tempCountdownTime);
                };
                // Time plus
                buttonTimePlus.onclick = function() { 
                    if (tempCountdownTime < 3600) {
                        tempCountdownTime += 30;
                    }

                    divTime.innerHTML = formatTime(tempCountdownTime);
                };
            // ------------------------------

            // Cancel button ----------
                buttonCancel.onclick = function () { gotoFrame("frameHome"); };
            // ------------------------------

            // Save button ----------
                buttonSave.onclick = function () {
                    // Save updated settings

                    // Operators
                    // Empty array
                    operators.length = 0;

                    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxOperators.length; i++) {
                        if (document.getElementById(checkboxOperators[i].id).checked == true) {
                            operators.push(checkboxOperators[i].id);    
                        }
                    }

                    // Number of questions
                    totalQuestions = tempTotalQuestions;

                    // Answer style
                    var radioAnswerStyle = document.getElementsByName("radioAnswerStyle");

                    for (var i = 0; i < radioAnswerStyle.length; i++) {                           
                        if (radioAnswerStyle[i].checked) {
                            answerStyle = radioAnswerStyle[i].id;
                        }
                    }

                    // Timer style
                    var radioTimer = document.getElementsByName("radioTimer");

                    for (var i = 0; i < radioTimer.length; i++) {                         
                        if (radioTimer[i].checked) {
                            timerStyle = radioTimer[i].id;
                        }
                    }

                    // Countdown time
                    countdownTime = tempCountdownTime;

                    gotoFrame("frameHome");
                };
            // ------------------------------
            break;


        case "frameQuiz":

            break;


        case "frameResults":

            break;


    }
}

// Format time
// Formats time as minutes and seconds (0:00)
function formatTime(time) {
    var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    var seconds = time - (minutes * 60);

    // Add 0 in front of seconds less than 10
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }

    return minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

// Go to home frame when app opens
gotoFrame("frameHome");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you introduced a client-side MVVM framework, I think you would get the modularization that you are looking for.  I have worked with, and really enjoy, [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).  Each frame could have it's own viewmodel, and you could create a single viewmodel that controls the flow logic between them.

For example, your settings frame would be built off of a `SettingsViewModel` that would hold all of the JavaScript, and perhaps contain a method on it that would return `currentSettings` to be used in other frames.  Additionally, you can test the behavior of this view model independent of the representation of it (the HTML).  Overall, this leads to a cleaner separation of concerns (application logic and presentation).

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fingers/W973t/5/) of a subset of the settings frame.